# Prevent renaming Shared Documents in a Teams site

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

Our users tend to rename the "Shared Documents" library in the SharePoint view of a Teams site. This of course causes Teams to break.
Acutally, I am not really sure, how they do it, I don't see any way to change the name and the url of an existing document library.
But, what is more important, I would like to prevent this.
How can I forbid users to make changes in a Teams site that would break the application working properly? Including, but probably not limited to change the url of the Shared Documents library and the General folder.
Thank you for any advice.

edit: Now I know, they mapping the sites as network share and since "Shared Documents" says nothing, the give the "folder" (that is actually the library) a more meaningful name.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you might change the name of the document library, but that shouldn't break it. What might break it, is renaming the created channel folders. And no, there's no (good) option to prevent this, as members get design permissions on the SharePoint site (which I think is a very bad idea)

There is an update on the roadmap that might help:
*See that a Teams channel is associated to a folder within the SharePoint library. Now it’s easy to tell which folders within your library have an associated Teams channel & chat associated to it – right from within the SharePoint user interface.*

see: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/What-s-new-for-your-intranet-in-Office-365/ba-p/194168

Comment: Just checked. Changing the name might not have an impact, but renaming it with Windows Explorer changes the URL too (Actually, this is the only way a normal user can change the document library URL, the other options are Designer or PowerShell), and this breaks Teams.

Comment: I didn't know that. It does remain however, that you cannot prevent this, unless you change the permissions of members from edit to contribute: http://www.oak3.org/sharepoint/permissions-on-a-group-connected-team-site/